# Loop through a folders/subfolders in directory and check for .gitignore files

Tags: bash

I have the following directory: `/c/methuselah/g2project`.

I want to loop through the folders/subfolders in that directory and check for any folder that contains a .gitignore file. Once it finds it, then I want to print out the subdirectory that contains the file onto the screen.

For example:

```
g2project/folder1/
g2project/folder1/subfolder1
g2project/folder2/
g2project/folder2/subfolder1
g2project/folder2/subfolder2
g2project/folder2/subfolder3
```

How do I do this in bash?

Comment: Is the output format important? e.g. would an absolute path be ok? is omitting the .gitignore file name important?

Comment: The format isn't important and the .gitignore file name can be a part of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` :

```
find /c/methuselah/g2project/ -name .gitignore
```

Another alternative would be to use the `globstar` option, which enable recursive matching with the `**` glob (can be used in any command since it is expanded by `bash`) :

```
shopt -s globstar
ls /c/methuselah/g2project/**/.gitignore
```